# Derivative of predictor function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, interpolation, machine-learning

Given some data `dat`, we would like to generate a *predictor function*. Therefore we use

```
 pdata = Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, dat];
 p = Predict[pdata, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
```

If one tries to take the derivative of `p[x]` via (here as an example at 2.)

```
 ND[p[x], x, 2.]
```

Mathematica returns `PredictorFunction::bfttype: "Invalid argument x. feature1 is a Numerical feature.` How can one perform a derivation of the *PredictorFunction*?

Answer (score 1):

I found it: It is the same case as with the integration of compiled functions. One has to use a wrapper:
`foo[x_?NumericQ] := p[x];`
The function `foo` can now be differentiated using `ND`.